# MySQL - Where is right place for condition?

Tags: mysql, sql

How to prevent sum(f)=0 from insert?

```
INSERT INTO `t_1` (a,b,c)
 SELECT d,e,sum(f)
 GROUP by d,e
```

I tried to add condition WHERE `sum(f)>0` to the query end. But it ends with error.

Comment: please indicate also the `FROM` clause.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When using a GROUP by you can filter out groups using the HAVING clause.

```
SELECT d,e,sum(f)  
GROUP by d,e
HAVING sum(f) > 0
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
INSERT INTO `t_1` (a,b,c)
SELECT   d,e,sum(f)
--FROM        -- don't forget this line  
GROUP by d,e
HAVING   sum(f) > 0
```

The difference between `WHERE` and `HAVING` clause is that the `HAVING` clause evaluates the aggregated (*functions like SUM(), COUNT(), MAX(), etc...*) condition while the `WHERE` clause cannot contain aggregate function.

Comment: Thank you for explain comment.

Answer (score 1):

Before `GROUP BY`, you can see the [select syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/select.html) in the MySQL documentation, it should be similar or the same when you have 'insert into' in front.

(Though maybe you meant 'HAVING ...' rather than 'WHERE').

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT d,e,sum(f)  
FROM mytable
GROUP by d,e
HAVING sum(f) > 0
```

OR...

place some logic in a trigger that throws an exception if that value is 0.